# Python Lowest Common CIDR

Tags: python, ip, subnet, cidr

Say I have two IPs: `startip = '63.223.64.0'` and `endip   = '63.223.127.255'`

I understand that in python `netaddr.iprange_to_cidrs(startip, endip)` will give you a list of CIDR subnets that fit exactly between the boundaries.  However, I was hoping to go for **one** CIDR subnet that covers it all even if it gives a few more IPs.

I prefer a function that does it, but I would also welcome any math/logic to calculate it and eventually turn it into code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [`netaddr.spanning_cidr`](http://pythonhosted.org/netaddr/api.html#netaddr.spanning_cidr) does the trick:

```
In [5]: netaddr.spanning_cidr(['63.223.64.0', '63.223.127.255'])
Out[5]: IPNetwork('63.223.64.0/18')
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module? It comes with Python 3, but is installable for Python 2.

```
import ipaddress
startip = ipaddress.IPv4Address('63.223.64.0')
endip = ipaddress.IPv4Address('63.223.127.255')
# summarize_address_range produces a generator, so force the results
networks = [n for n in ipaddress.summarize_address_range(startip, endip)]
print(networks)
# [IPv4Network('63.223.64.0/18')]
```

Comment: Issue is I have python 2.6.6 and no way of installing new modules.  but I'll give it a shot.  thanks.